# Common User management for Django project ecosystem

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-database

I have been working with Django for the last few months and have built some projects in it. I was wondering whether it is possible for the distinct Django projects to share a common-use authentication and authorization project?

There is a user management portal for the internal employees where the admin can add various employees to different user roles (like a manager, etc.). I will then define in the other projects what user role can access what part of the application statically.

Additional parameters:

- There will be read-and-write operations on the user from all the projects
- There will be user-specific data (**not** user role specific **user** specific)

Until now I have looked at the Django multi-database support which can solve my user authentication problem, but there is a catch in the authorization part where the foreign key constraints cause some problems in the models

Currently, I have written a database router and am creating a user management portal for the authentication of users from a single source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could think of a microservices based architecture where 1 of your Django project will act as a `user_auth` microservice.

All requests related to login, forgot password, change password, registration, etc can we routed to that Django project (`user_auth`) microservice. This application will create the JWT token. You can use [djangorestframework-simplejwt](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt) for creating our JWT tokens.

And you can write `authentication_classes` for all your other Django projects to receive, decode and understand these JWT tokens created from `user_auth` microservice.

If you have a custom user model, you can have copy of the User model in every Django project and then you could keep them as `managed=False` everywhere except the `user_auth` microservice. Or you could have it as a private pip package.

There is much more to it, but this is the basic idea. I've had many projects with this structure which are in production on a scale of few millions.